# Regex for URL that matches a format, but exclude parameters that match that URL format

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to comb through some logs. I'm looking for logs that have the format `http://something/something.php`. I currently have this:

```
https?.*?\.php
```

The problem with this is that some of my logs have URLs with URLs in their parameters, like this:

```
http://hello/world.asp?redirect=http://something/else.php
http://hello/blah.asp?abc=/blah/blah.php
```

Some logs contain multiple parameters, and a URL can be in any, not necessarily at the end of the line. All those get matched as well. In the example above, the actual URL is a `.asp`, it just happens that it has a `.php` parameter.

What kind of regex could I use to only match when the *actual* target is a `.php`, as opposed to one of its parameters being a URL with a `.php`.

Comment: Use [`(?<![a-zA-Z]=)https?[^?]*?\.php`](https://regex101.com/r/G3hrsw/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, this is much better, but please see my updated question with the second example. I didn't notice but some are relative, ie without `http`.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/G3hrsw/2, the 2 inputs are not matched.

Comment: as @WiktorStribiżew said, but one question: do you need the whole URL, in case its a PHP-target or just the url-part and not the param-part?

because Wiktors Regex works just fine if you need only the url-part.

Comment: Look at the URI module on CPAN and borrow the regex it uses to parse strings in the constructor.

Comment: @Juicy: Could you please clarify the requirements? Is my solution working for you? If not, why? Please post the code to remove any misunderstanding.

Comment: @simbabque: *"borrow the regex"* Why not just use the module?

Comment: @Borodin I don't see how it would help parse a log file. It's meant to represent and perform actions on URIs. That's not the use case here.  I also don't think the OP is actually using Perldoc Perl. Just something with PCRE and the question doesn't have that tag. There is no Perl code in it after all.

Comment: @simbabque: *" I also don't think the OP is actually using Perldoc Perl"* I'm not sure what that means. Are you saying that they may not be using Perl, but some other language with a Perl-like regex engine?

Comment: @simbabque: *"I don't see how it would help parse a log file"* But you advocate excising and using the regex pattern from the module. What remains is mostly accessors to parts of the URL by object methods, which seems to me to be excellent practice. Were the OP to rip out a regex and squeeze it into working, they would still be unable to maintain their own code. What is your objection to *not* using the module, other than speculation that the OP may be using a completely different language?

Comment: @Juicy: What programming language are you using? Can you show us your code?

Answer (score 1):

Restricting yourself to a regex solution is never a good idea

Use the [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) module to handle URL strings conveniently

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use URI;

while ( <DATA> ) {

    chomp;

    my $url = URI->new($_);

    my $ok = $url->scheme =~ /\Ahttps?\z/ && $url->path =~ /\.php\z/;

    printf qq{URL "%s" %s\n}, $url, $ok ? "matches" : "doesn't match";
}

__DATA__
http://something/something.php
http://hello/world.asp?redirect=http://something/else.php
http://hello/blah.asp?abc=/blah/blah.php
```

#### output

```
URL "http://something/something.php" matches
URL "http://hello/world.asp?redirect=http://something/else.php" doesn't match
URL "http://hello/blah.asp?abc=/blah/blah.php" doesn't match
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of matching any character in the url - exclude the '?' and start from the beginning (^)

```
^https?[^\?]*\.php
```